# Network shares over 4TB

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing

We have our project files stored on a Windows 2008R2. Now the space on that 4TB drive is filling rapidly and we are soon either forced to expand the drive or move older file out from the drive. The question is (someone in our IT team claimed this) will there be problems with some applications if we expand the share to over 4TB. Our organization uses some older applications which are claimed to have problems, but noone can say for sure if there will be problems or not.

So, does getting over the 4TB threshold cause problems with older applications on shared drives? 4TB has been a problem on local drives on older computers, but will it be problem on shared drive on client applications?

Technical information: The server is virtual server VMware ESXi 5.1. The 4TB drive is direct iSCSI-drive (not via VMware) from Dell Equallogic.

Comment: I've never seen applications have issues with large disks ...Windows supports GPT partitions that allow you to go over 4TB. The best way to find out would be to contact your vendors and see what they say about it.

Comment: Most of the possibly problematic applications are old legacy programs with no actual support, so unfortunately this isnt a real option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only concern that I have is that 4TB is, in my experience, a pretty big NTFS volume. CHKDSK has gotten a lot better in the last few Windows releases, but you will likely still have a multi-hour outage if you take filesystem corruption on a volume that big. (Fewer large files would make a faster CHKDSK run as compared to more numerois small files.)

If such an outage is acceptable then I think you're fine to grow the volume. Windows can definitely handle it.

You might consider relocating critical files for which you might want to maintain more availability to another, smaller NTFS volume and using a mount point or DFS-N to "glue" it to the larger volume.

Having seen multi-hour CHKDSK runs I am somewhat reticent to use NTFS volumes that are so large in production. At the very least, I try to use them for "archival" data that can tolerate some loss of availability.

---

Edit: I don't get too concerned about applications. Microsoft's [Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562082(v=vs.85).aspx) (ACT) contains a lot of functionality to "coerce" unwilling applications into working. As an example, the [EmulateGetDiskFreeSpace fix](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff720129(v=ws.10).aspx) can cause Windows to fabricate a free space number allowing legacy applications that have integer overflows with >2GB of free disk space to work.

I've had a *lot* of success getting finicky applications to work using the ACT.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Ive always thought using mount points as ugly and hard-to-manage solution, but you make excellent points altogether. And your experience gives your claims a lot of credibility. I think this might be the way we go ahead. It requires quite a bit of work to change.

Answer (score 9):

They're *might* be issues. The question is how low your application will be layered when accessing the filesystem. Normally they're should be no issue if Windows can handle it as your applications *should* use the Windows API to access the filesystem on a lower level.

Of course better be safe than sorry, so put it to the test before moving to production.

Comment: Unfortunately we lack the possibility of making a proper test environment from this specific server due lack of resources.

Comment: @Kemu79: then it sounds like what you need to do is either create a new share of an appropriate size and move certain applications to point there OR, if that is't feasible, backup everything you have, upgrade it and see what breaks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be more concerned about the direct iSCSI mapping of storage *(versus something that's on the vSphere cluster and has those protections)*.

You can increase the LUN size on the Dell, so there are obviously more storage resources available to you. But at this point, would it make more sense to create a new LUN and move files to it? If that's an option and your application(s) don't require a single contiguous partition, that's what I'd do. This is more of a management suggestion and not a technical limitation. This is already a GPT disk and the magic barrier was 2.2TB on partition size.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like such huge NTFS volumes due to chkdsk issues. See Evan Andersons answer on that one.
Also bear in mind that chkdsk not only will take ages if it comes in effect, but ALSO may need more RAM than the VM has available.
The rule of thumb is roughly 1 GB of RAM for each 1TB of disk-space, to be on the safe side. (Especially on volumes with lots of small files.)

The big worry with legacy applications is that they go haywire on checks for free disk-space.
Just reading/writing files is usually OK because that goes through the Windows systems-calls and the application itself won't be creating anything bigger than it can handle (hopefully...).
But if it asks Windows "how much free disk-space is there?" (common practice prior to writing a new file) it may get an answer it's not prepared for.
E.g. Old Borland C/C++, Pascal, Object-Pascal en Delphi programs are a bit notorious for this. The Borland runtime libraries that these programs share are a bit flaky in this regard. And there are still a lot of these out there. 
Visual Basic 4 is also a well-known problem case.

Of course it may also be that you legacy applications never trigger this behavior. There is no way to predict what will happen.

I would setup an extra separate drive less than 1 TB in size on this VM. Move the folders for the legacy stuff onto this drive. Then you can safely expand the original disk without having to worry about this.
If the legacy apps approach the data via shares they won't even notice they are now talking to another disk.
If the legacy stuff is running on the server itself, depends on a certain disk-layout and won't deal nicely with a change of path you can always mount the extra volume on top of the original folder on the larger disk. A bit messy but that works.

Answer (score 1):

While you shouldn't have any issues with larger than 4Tb disks you have always got the option to just move entire directories to other disks and to create hardlinks to them. This will only work if you have directories of files and not one huge 4Tb file. If you have multiple directories you can move any of these to another disk and have the space on that other disk accessible.
The tool for this is mklink.